# How to keep track of programs that I've installed from the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I've installed many apps from my terminal to the point that I can't keep up with how many apps I've installed. These apps include; ruby on rails, node-sass, some npm apps, and many more.

The problem is that I can't see these apps in my application folder (I'm using a Mac). 
Where can I locate these apps? 
How can I keep track of them? 
How can I uninstall them?

Answer (score 1):

You can track all of this from your Terminal. The best way is just to use the `gem uninstall <gem-name>` command.

However, you can find your installed gems via path.  The locations will depend on what ruby version manager you are using (RVM, Chruby, Rbenv). The ruby gems will be located in your current ruby versions gem path.  You can check your environment variables to find the path.

```
~ env

# a bunch of other variables omitted
RUBY_VERSION=2.3.0
GEM_ROOT=/Users/<your-user-name>/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
GEM_PATH=/Users/<your-user-name/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/Users/<your-user-name/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0  


# You'll find them at one of those paths inside of the gems directory.
~ ls $GEM_ROOT/gems
actionmailer-4.2.5.1             net-telnet-0.1.1
```

## Removing Ruby Gems

You can find what libraries (GEMS) you have installed for your current Ruby version from your shell with gem list.

```
~ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]

~ gem list
timecop (0.8.1, 0.8.0)
warden (1.2.6)

~ gem uninstall warden
```

## Removing NPM Packages

Pretty straightforward and comparable to removing ruby gems(both RubyGems and NPM are package managers after all!).  The `-g` flag is to show the global packages only and the `--depth=0` argument is so you don't have be overwhelmed by the dependencies of each package.  If you want to remove only the **local packages** (aka, for the current directory/project), same command sans flags `npm uninstall <package>`.

```
~ npm list -g --depth=0
├── ember-cli@1.13.13
├── phantomjs@1.9.19
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what distro you are using, here is some info for `apt` based ones.

To see your recent history: cat /var/log/apt/history.log

If you need to view a rotated log file (older than 1 month usually): `zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz` (replace number as needed)

You can also see your typing history using `history` command.

To uninstall an app: `sudo apt-get remove <package name>`